# Rails/ruby undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have simple class with class's and private's methods

```
class XmlConnection

 def self.guitarmania
    request = HTTParty.get(site_url)
    handle_errors(request)
  end

 private

  def handle_errors(request)
    if request.code == 200
      request
    else
      raise 'Connection error'
    end
  end



end
```

when i call `XmlConnection.guitarmania` i get

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'handle_errors' for
>   XmlConnection:Class

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When you're using a self. for a class method, all private methods also need to use self to be accessed from within it. The following will work:

```
class XmlConnection

 def self.guitarmania
    request = HTTParty.get(site_url)
    handle_errors(request)
  end

 private

  def self.handle_errors(request)
    if request.code == 200
      request
    else
      raise 'Connection error'
    end
  end
end
```

If all your methods will be class methods, you could wrap them all in a self to make it a bit more readable. This works exactly as above:

```
class XmlConnection
   class << self
     def guitarmania
        request = HTTParty.get(site_url)
        handle_errors(request)
      end

     private

      def handle_errors(request)
        if request.code == 200
          request
        else
          raise 'Connection error'
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: `private` in the first snippet does not declare `self.handle_errors` as private class method. Use `private_class_method :handle_errors` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define handle_errors on the class as well:

```
def self.handle_errors(request)
```